how is the optimal component selection on PLS-LDA?
I currently have a project on applying dimensionality reduction using PLS to the LDA classification method. Is the determination of the components used in LDA tested using the LDA model or using the PLS-DA model? If you would like, can anyone tell me the kore r for this analysis. Where is a reliable source that can be used as a reference for the application of the PLS-LDA combination? I have seen many references about PLS-DA but the formulas used are different. Therefore, I really need a valid reference for me to apply in my writing. thank you.
